# jquery datepicker formatting not lining up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Just using standard jquery datepicker and my calendar looks like this (dates are way outside the calendar frame).  Any ideas how to fix?

page has :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet'>
```

[image]

Comment: You're either missing the correct stylesheet or you're loading _other_ styles that are conflicting. Please revise your post to show us the _entire_ context.

Comment: Found it. thank you. Styles are conflicting.

Comment: Please delete your question or provide an answer. Abandoned posts are ugly.